IntelliJ cannot download commons-lang3-3.12.0-sources
I am not seeing any quick documentation on commons-lang. I go into the decompiled .class file and click "Download Sources" and get this:
10:45:40 am: Executing 'ijDownloadSources5e1c23e0-5bf'...


> Task :ijDownloadSources5e1c23e0-5bf FAILED
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':ijDownloadSources5e1c23e0-5bf' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Type 'IjDownloadTask' property 'collectionProvider' cannot be resolved:  Could not find commons-lang3-3.12.0-sources.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0). Searched in the following locations:  file:/Users/rob.bram/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0-sources.jar. Reason: An input file collection couldn't be resolved, making it impossible to determine task inputs. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#unresolvable_input for more details about this problem.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
1 actionable task: 1 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/58/4bhh_y2955x_rrk219q06r2w0000gp/T/ijDownloadSources8.gradle' line: 36

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ijDownloadSources5e1c23e0-5bf'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':downloadSources_65dedda4-dd40-4228-8913-a0787c03f670'.
   > Could not find commons-lang3-3.12.0-sources.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/rob.bram/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0-sources.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 318ms
10:45:41 am: Execution finished 'ijDownloadSources5e1c23e0-5bf'.

I have this in build.gradle:
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs += files("node_modules")
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

I do see quick documentation on other APIs. Having trouble figuring out what's wrong with this one.

i had a same issue.if it is possible, try to downgrade ur intellij it worked for me

The normal way to deal with getting hold of dependencies is to add a repository to the build script, and by far the most popular is Maven Central. So add:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

and you should be good to go.

Lovely! We had mavenLocal() and then mavenCentral(). After commenting out the former, it downloads source and docs OK for the commons.lang. Well, thank you.
